# ASP.Net MVC Stongly Typed Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a stongly typed view in an ASP.Net MVC project I'm working on, the view is just an index page that lists the contents of a SQL table in a grid.

I now want to add the functionality to filter this list. I've tried to do this by creating a form in the view with a drop down list containing the values you can filter by. The idea being that when the user submits that form it triggers the controllers Post index method which will grab the selected value the dropdown list from the FormCollection passed into the method.

For example my 2 index methods look like this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DevAdminEntities db = new DevAdminEntities();
        ViewData["StatusDropDown"] = new SelectList(db.TaskStatuses, "TaskStatusId", "StatusName");
        return View(db.Tasks);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        DevAdminEntities db = new DevAdminEntities();
        ViewData["StatusDropDown"] = new SelectList(db.TaskStatuses, "TaskStatusId", "StatusName");
        return View(from t in db.Tasks where t.Projects.ProjectId == int.Parse(Request.Form["StatusDropDown"]) new { t, t.Projects});
    }
```

The page displays fine when it loads in its unfiltered form but when I click the submit button to apply a filter I get the following error

"*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Int32]' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DevAdmin.Models.Tasks]'.*"

The view looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DevAdmin.Models.Tasks>>" %>    
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</asp:Content>    
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    
    <h2>Tasks</h2>        
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Filters</legend>           
            <p>
               <%= Html.DropDownList("StatusDropDown") %>
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
            </p>                    
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>            
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                TaskId
            </th>
            <th>
                Subject
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
        </tr>    
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.TaskId }) %> |
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TaskId })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.TaskId) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Subject) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Description) %>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    <% } %>    
    </table>    
    <p>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>    
</asp:Content>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One more tip: it's in general better to have your filter as a "GET" method and not "POST". This way people can bookmark their filter, and you can create links to specific filters. Filter is an action that does not change anything in the resources, so it should be "GET".

Comment: Sounds interesting any pointers on how I would do this? Would I still use the form on my view for submitting the filter? Also could the page still work if no filters are defined?

Thanks

Comment: <% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get)) {%>

Comment: You should check in the controlleraction whether there's a filter defined. (check for null)

Comment: Like Thomas says, you will only have one Index() method , that has the FormsCollection param. If that param is empty, you don't filter, otherwise you start filtering.

Comment: Actually if you only have one field, you don't have to use FormsCollection just have your method like : Index(string StatusDropDown) .

Comment: Thanks for the tip, one thing though doing the FormMethod.Get puts ?StatusDropDown=1 Onto the end of my URL, is there anyway to pass this in a more MVC way without it being a query string. Something like tasks/index/filter/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it kinda says in the errormessage what you do wrong.

The view expects a `IEnumerable1<Tasks>` passed to it as Model, but you're passing a `new { t, t.Projects}`

Also, put some breathing room in your code..

replace

```
return View(*hard to read code here*);
```

with

```
int currentStatus = int.Parse(Request.Form["StatusDropDown"];
var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(t => t.ProjectId.Equals(currentStatus));
return View("Index", tasks.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 1):

1) `return View(db.Tasks);` returns an IEnumerable

2) `return View(from t in db.Tasks where t.Projects.ProjectId == int.Parse(Request.Form["StatusDropDown"]) new { t, t.Projects});` return an IQueryable.

So you have to options:
Either change 1) into `return View(db.Tasks).AsQueryable()` and in your view change the type into IQueryable.

Or change 2)  into  `return View(from t in db.Tasks where t.Projects.ProjectId == int.Parse(Request.Form["StatusDropDown"]) new { t, t.Projects}).AsEnumerable();`

IEnumerable is for Linq to Object.
IQueryable is for Linq to SQL and other entitities.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the ActionResult expects

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formValues)
```

Where FormCollection Iis an IEnumerable type. However, in your view you are posting back the selected index from the drop down which is an `Int32`:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("StatusDropDown") %>
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />
```

You should change the ActionResult signature to accept an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

the form is posting the value attached to the drop down, change the method parameter from FormCollection to int[]